# How to Customize UISlider?

Tags: iphone, uislider

I understand how you can have a minimum track and maximum track image, and how it can be stretchable. However, for my needs, that might not be enough control.

I have a situation where on the left hand side (minimum track) I need to display two different colors, based on data. The left hand side actually represents two pieces of data, but yet there still exists only a single thumb between minimum and maximum.

so how can i do this???

Any sample code??

i actually want like this

[photo link](http://www.flickr.com/photos/41839029@N06/3946387749/)

On left hand side it is of grinish color but when it exceeds the thumb image it becomes red..

Answer (score 8):

In your .h file

```
IBOutlet UISlider *slide;
```

in your .m file

```
UIImage *minImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected.png"];
    UIImage *maxImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"];
    UIImage *tumbImage= [UIImage imageNamed:@"thumb.png"];
    minImage=[minImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
    maxImage=[maxImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
    [slide setMinimumTrackImage:minImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

unselected.png and selected.png are the images that act as bar and thumb.png which slide over the bar.

Answer (score 3):

Put your image swapping code in your slider value-reading method, which is usually:

```
-(IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender; {}
```

Swap your custom green image with a custom red image whenever your slider value reaches some predefined value. See example below.

```
// Switches the -thumbImage between an ivar named highImage and lowImage 
// when the slider passes the halfway point  

if (sliderValue > 0.5) {
    [self updateSliderThumbWithImage:self.highImage];
} else {
    [self updateSliderThumbWithImage:self.lowImage];
}
```

define the slider image update method like this:

```
-(void)updateSliderThumbWithImage:(UIImage *)image;
{
    [self.slider setThumbImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.slider setThumbImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}

// You have to set thumb images for both states  
// or your image will vanish when user slides it. 
// Not sure if you have to do the same with the track image, though.
```

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I can visualize what you need (any chance you can post a sketch?), but do a search for UISlider and you can find some pretty creative uses.  Otherwise you can create your own custom UIControl.

[image]
<sub>(source: [texlege.com](http://www.texlege.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/uislider-track.png))</sub>