# Using a Custom UISlider - Cocoa Touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

Okay I've created a slider in photoshop which I want to use as a volume button in my application using a uislider. How do I make it so i can use a custom uislider design in my app?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Customize UISlider ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459030/how-to-customize-uislider)

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I'm still new to the language, im not 100% sure how to do it